# Java - name of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've the following question:

Why is it not necessary to use a name of the list before the add-statement `(add (pipedInstanceIterator.next()))` ?

Thanks.

```
public class InstanceList extends ArrayList<Instance> implements Serializable, Iterable<Instance>, AlphabetCarrying
...
public void addThruPipe (Iterator<Instance> ii)
{
    //for debug
    Iterator<Instance> pipedInstanceIterator = pipe.newIteratorFrom(ii);
    while (pipedInstanceIterator.hasNext())
    {   
        add (pipedInstanceIterator.next());
        //System.out.println("Add instance " + pipedInstanceIterator.next().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're extending ArrayList, so the method is implicitly called on `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InstanceList` is a sub-class of `ArrayList`, so it can execute any public or protected methods of that class without specifying the instance for which they should be executed.

Comment: Okay. One last question: Is it because of the Collection ArrayList or does it  apply in general (relationship supper - sub class)?

Comment: @user3680103 it applies to any sub-class.

Comment: But why does it not work if I call the add-method at the main-method and it gives the warning "cannot cast a static to a non-static reference" ?

Comment: @user3680103 Because the main method is static, so it doesn't have a reference to any instance of InstanceList.

Answer (score 0):

Because InstanceList extends ArrayList, any unspecified methods will be run on it. So your adding to instance list

Comment: But why does it not work if I call the add-method at the main-method and it gives the warning "cannot cast a static to a non-static reference" ?

Comment: In what context do you get this error? It usually happens when you try to call a method from class(add), not from object of that class (e.g. InstanceList)